# Putting Rails app on GAE

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.4 on windows. What are the steps to put my rails application on google app engine and allow only authorized users to view it?

Comment: go for heroku. GAE for rails is a pain. They don't promote activerecord.

Comment: Heroku heroku heroku.  Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be GAE?  If you just want a cloud solution you could maybe look at heroku (http://heroku.com/).

If it has to be GAE you'll need to make sure your app runs on jruby.  You're also not going to be able to use active record.

Here's a good guide on how you can get a rails app on GAE:

http://olabini.com/blog/2009/04/jruby-on-rails-on-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be GAE. I just need to be able to put my rails app on a website where a limited set of users can view it. I have never deployed a rails app before so I am not sure which is the best way to get this done.

Comment: Heroku is definitely the easiest